# Istio egress traffic routing - retries without egress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I am trying to implement the retry feature in VirtualService for egress traffic external to the mesh. This does not seem to work. Should we always configure egress gateway for retry to work?

```
 apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: httpbin-external
spec:
  hosts:
    - httpbin.org
  ports:
    - number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    - number: 443
      name: tls
      protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  exportTo:
  - "."
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: external-httpbin
spec:
  hosts:
    - httpbin.org
  http:
  - timeout: 3s
    route:
      - destination:
          host: httpbin.org
        weight: 100
    retries:
      attempts: 5
      perTryTimeout: 2s
      retryOn: gateway-error,connect-failure,refused-stream,retriable-4xx,5xx
```

Answer (score 0):

virtual service you had shared doesn't have egress gateway linked to it.

gateways:

- istio-egressgateway

Comment: This is my question. Can retry for egress only work with Gateway? Istio docs does not state that.

Comment: To do proper traffic routing from virtual service to egress gateway its required.  More information about same is mentioned in istio docs.  [link] (https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/) 4.  Define a VirtualService to direct traffic from the sidecars to the egress gateway and from the egress gateway to the external service: if not an envoy HTTPfilter has to be created which gets applied to all sidecars [link] (https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/router_filter#x-envoy-retry-on)

Comment: I was able to get this working with VirtualService without using an Egress Gateway.

Comment: @Upen, Seems like your issue has been resolved. If Yes, can you please post the resolution steps you have followed as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.